# What's the best way to put two inputs side by side in a form using Bulma CSS?

Tags: bulma

I just started using Bulma to style my site and am having a hard time figuring out whether the framework supports putting two form fields side-by-side.  The best example would be first and last name of a user.

[Bulma's form group](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#form-group) looked promising but it doesn't seem to work if you want two separate fields.

I also started using the grid (`columns` and `column` classes) but it got messy with spacing.

Here's what I'm trying to do (the first name and last name part):

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You can use [Bulma responsive helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/modifiers/responsive-helpers/).

```
<div class="field-group">
 <div class="field is-inline-block-desktop">
  <label class="label">First Name</label>
  <div class="control">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Alex">
  </div>
 </div>

<div class="field is-inline-block-desktop">
 <label class="label">Last Name</label>
 <div class="control">
  <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Smith">
 </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

[Example fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fbt86o2h/)

Edit:
Just went trough official documentation, it's recommended to use "*is-horizontal* modifier on the *field* container".

See more [here](https://bulma.io/documentation/form/general/#horizontal-form).

Comment: Thanks! It might make sense to just edit my answer instead of posting this new one since it's just a slight variation?  The responsive helper classes are definitely nice; I can add `is-flex-tablet` as an additional class to where `field-group` is, but I still need all the additional CSS to make sure the labels are spaced properly and take up the full row. The `is-horizontal` modifier is a good idea as well but it means you have to put your labels to the outside (which I don't want) and also (I believe) that you can only have one label per row (I need two, one for each field).

Answer (score 5):

Use Bulma Levels: "In a level-item, you can then insert almost anything you want: a title, a button, a text input, or just simple text."
[Bulma Levels](https://bulma.io/documentation/layout/level/)

```
<div class="level">
  <div class="level-left">
    <div class="level-item">
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">First Name</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Alex">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item">
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Middle Name</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Bob">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="level-item">
      <div class="field">
        <label class="label">Last Name</label>
        <div class="control">
          <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Smith">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

I persisted with the columns classes and got it working. The use of columns class allows you to use the convenient `is-half` [class](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/sizes/) that applies to a column.

First use the following override style to help with spacing:

```
<style>.small-padding{padding-top:0}</style>
```

Then include this new `small-padding` class with the column class to get nicely spaced input boxes:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
  <div class="column is-half small-padding"><input name="fname" class="input" placeholder="First Name..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-half small-padding"><input name="lname" class="input" placeholder="Last Name..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-full small-padding"><input name="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Email Address..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-full small-padding"><label>Address</label><input name="address" class="input" placeholder="Full Address..."></div>
  <div class="column is-full small-padding"><input name="city" class="input" placeholder="Suburb..."></div>
  <div class="column is-half small-padding"><input name="state" class="input" placeholder="State..."></div>
  <div class="column is-half small-padding"><input name="postal_code" class="input" placeholder="Postcode..."></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Notes

- Only required one custom class to override padding-top: `.small-padding{padding-top:0}`.
- Uses the `is-multiline` [class](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/options/#multiline) to allow multiple lines of fields that wrap to the next line, when necessary.
- The `is-mobile` [class](https://bulma.io/documentation/columns/responsiveness/#mobile-columns) allows multiple fields even when on mobile - remove this if you want fields to stack under each other on a mobile.

**EDIT... For Bulma 0.9.0+**

Bulma now has [spacing helpers](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/), so it can be now done without any custom css: replace the `small-padding` custom class with bulma's new `pt-0` spacing helper. So it is as simple as:

```
<fieldset>
<div class="columns is-mobile is-multiline">
  <div class="column is-half pt-0"><input name="fname" class="input" placeholder="First Name..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-half pt-0"><input name="lname" class="input" placeholder="Last Name..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-full pt-0"><input name="email" type="email" class="input" placeholder="Email Address..." required></div>
  <div class="column is-full pt-0"><label>Address</label><input name="address" class="input" placeholder="Full Address..."></div>
  <div class="column is-full pt-0"><input name="city" class="input" placeholder="Suburb..."></div>
  <div class="column is-half pt-0"><input name="state" class="input" placeholder="State..."></div>
  <div class="column is-half pt-0"><input name="postal_code" class="input" placeholder="Postcode..."></div>
</div>
</fieldset>
```

Notes

- Use the `pd-0` [class](https://bulma.io/documentation/helpers/spacing-helpers/) to help with spacing.

Comment: SHould be the selected answer imo

Answer (score 1):

I worked on this for a bit and still couldn't find a great solution via Bulma so ended up writing my own class `field-group` to help.

**CSS**

```css
/* Target tablet and up */
@media screen and (min-width: 769px), print {
  .field-group {
    display: flex;
  }

  /* Give margin on left if not first field */
  .field-group > .field:not(:first-child) {
    margin-left: 0.75rem;
  }

  /* Give margin on right if not last field */
  .field-group > .field:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 0.75rem;
  }

  /* Allow fields to grow to fill up all horizontal space */
  .field-group > .field {
    flex: 1 1 0;
  }

  /* Remove bottom margin if grouped fields are the last in the form */
  .field-group:last-child > .field {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}

/* If grouped fields aren't the last in the form, give them bottom margin */
.field-group:not(:last-child) > .field {
  margin-bottom: 0.75rem;
}
```

**HTML**

```html
<!-- Wrapper for fields we want to be on one line -->
<div class="field-group">
  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">First Name</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Alex">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <label class="label">Last Name</label>
    <div class="control">
      <input class="input" type="text" placeholder="e.g Smith">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This allows you to nest several fields in a `div` with the `field-group` class and they'll split the space available to them on a single line in Tablet and up screens.  On mobile, they'll move to their own line.

Will not close this out as I hope there's a more elegant solution!